# GFortran runtime errors

Tags: file, error-handling, io, gfortran, netbeans-7

```
    ***
    
          CHARACTER W*1
          DIMENSION IR(1319), IC(1319)
          CALL SCREEN (6)   
          OPEN (1,FILE='FLOWER.DAT')
          DO I=1,1319
             READ (1,021,END=035) IR(I),IC(I)
     021     FORMAT (I3,I3)
          END DO
     035  CLOSE(1)
          DO J=1,1319  
             CALL PIXEL (1,IR(J),IC(J))     ; Reading pixel data from the input data file
          END DO
          READ (*,'(A)') W
          CALL SCREEN (3) ; This assembly routine changing text mode to graphics mode 
          END
    **************************
```

How to solve Input/Output error in GFortran using NetBeans IDE 7.4 Version?
Run time errors given below:

```
    Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.
    Backtrace for this error:
    #0  0x6f8aecb4
    #1  0x6f89d642
    #2  0x401138
    read from master failed
                           : Input/output error
    RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 819ms)
    
    FLOWER.DAT file opened in Plain text mode.
```

Are there any modifications required?
If modifications are required let me know how to modify which file.
screen.s, pixel.s files are assembly routines.

Comment: Compile with debugging enabled and run under a debugger.  This may have nothing to do with gfortran.  It could be a problem with screen.s and pixel.s and anything else that appears to be mucking with unit 6.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. You can enable debugging checks with the `gfortran -g -fcheck=all` options. Please re-run your code with these options.